# Normal & counterparts

Tags: riddle, computer-science

```
We are brothers of like paths
order is vital to us.

There is the straightforward one,
always climbing till he's done.

The other two can't stand the heights;
we bunjee jump at middle sites,
to start again with all our mights.

But one of us dropped more,
to see more of hell's floor,
to gain just a bit more lore.

The last ends up where he started,
but isn't visiting the same place...fainthearted?
```

Answer (score 8):

To me, this appears to describe:

> The shapes of four famous graphs: $y = x$, $y = sin(x)$, $y = cos(x)$ and $y = tan(x)$.

*We are brothers of like paths*
*order is vital to us.*

> 'We' are **graphs**, *paths* whose value (y) depends on another *ordered* value (x).

*There is the straightforward one,*
*always climbing till he's done.*

> $y = x$
>  An ever-climbing line:
>
>  [image]

*The other two can't stand the heights;*
*we bunjee jump at middle sites,*
*to start again with all our mights.*

> *[Another] two* are sin(x) and cos(x), lines which constantly rise and plunge back down through zero, as if *bungee jumping*.
>
>  $y = sin(x)$
>
>  [image]
>
>  $y = cos(x)$
>
>  [image]

*But one of us dropped more,*
*to see more of hell's floor,*
*to gain just a bit more lore.*

*The last ends up where he started,*
*but isn't visiting the same place...fainthearted?*

> If we interpret these two paragraphs together, these could be seen to describe y = tan(x). This one '*dropped more to see more of Hell's floor*' since the line goes way past zero into the negative numbers, veering off towards (negative) infinity. In fact, the lines followed by *[this] last [brother]* start at (negative) infinity and end at (positive) infinity - a bit like ending '*where he started*' and yet not '*visiting the same place*'.
>
>  $y = tan(x)$
>
>  [image]

*<sub>All images created using Google Search.</sub>*

Comment: The last one could also be rot13(n pvepyr)

Comment: @El-Guest Yes I did consider that, but it seemed to me that really would be 'visiting the same place', so I ended up discounting it...

Comment: This is very interesting! Not the intended answer though. I'm gonna include a more specific tag.